# C# text box latency

Tags: c#, latency

I am streaming data from an inertial sensor into a C# application. Using a bool as a switch, I print the incoming values to a series of text boxes, as so:

```
    if (bStreaming == true)
    {
     textboxTX.Invoke(new Action(() => textboxTX.Text = Convert.ToString(result[0])));
     textboxTY.Invoke(new Action(() => textboxTY.Text = Convert.ToString(result[1])));
     textboxTZ.Invoke(new Action(() => textboxTZ.Text = Convert.ToString(result[2])));
    }
```

The problem is, as soon as I start this loop, the rest of my application slows down considerably and starts to lag. Am I doing this wrong? I have tried starting the loop inside a new thread, and see the same result.

Comment: How frequently do you update the UI?

Comment: It's unlikely that this code itself cause the problem. Update 3 textboxes on UI is a very straightforward operation and should be executed almost immediately, but if you do it in loop with no delay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter what thread calls the invoke method. If it's called in a tight loop it will drain your resources anyway. Try `await`ing `Task.Delay(millis)` for some time before each iteration. You can even use this as a sort of "minimum time" using the following code:

```
while (true)
{
    var updateFrequency = Task.Delay(1000);
    if (bStreaming == true)
    {
     textboxTX.Invoke(new Action(() => textboxTX.Text = Convert.ToString(result[0])));
     textboxTY.Invoke(new Action(() => textboxTY.Text = Convert.ToString(result[1])));
     textboxTZ.Invoke(new Action(() => textboxTZ.Text = Convert.ToString(result[2])));
    }
    await updateFrequency;
}
```

Comment: I noted you unaccepted the answer, is there some problem with it that I can address?

Answer (score 3):

If data rate is high, then you should consider using batch updates.
Instead of updating as soon as data received, consider making updates for each second, or when the number of messages exceeds a threshold.

You can use a backgroundworker to process data and update UI at some intervals. You may refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811048/how-can-i-use-a-backgroundworker-with-a-timer-tick).

Comment: Thanks! The data rate is very high, so i will add a batch update.