# C# when mouse move event, time loop stops

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling

I have created a game where you need to shoot a mole which moves randomly on screen every 0.5 seconds.

When I move my mouse over the screen without stopping, the time-loop seems to freeze until the mouse stops moving.

I have an on-mouse move event which refreshes to screen,
and a time-loop event which updates the form every 0.5 seconds. How can I make both events run without interfering with each other?

Comment: Can you share your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand you properly, but by the clues you have given I can suggest you by making one method a thread process would do the trick. Since its the `UIElement` you are changing, you must use `Begininvoke` method.

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate();
private void Invoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mole.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(InvokeMethod));
}
public void InvokeMethod()
{
    // change your mole position here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use Backgroundworker. Subscribe DoWork event of Backgroundworker. And You can count your timer or watch inside that event.

[You can look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811048/how-can-i-use-a-backgroundworker-with-a-timer-tick)