# How to access a Control from a different Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can I access a control from a thread other than the thread it was created on, avoiding the cross-thread error?

Here is my sample code for this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(foo);
    t.Start();
}

private  void foo()
{
    this.Text = "Test";
}
```

Comment: There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow about this.

Comment: If you are new to Winforms I suggest start with WPF. Many might disagree but imho Winforms is dead. In WPF this issue was solved by queuing operations to each component.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the-t  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650109/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-any-help-plz    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809864/how-to-access-a-form-control-from-system-timers-timer-cross-thread-problem

Comment: Lots of potential duplicates, not a single close vote.

Answer (score 14):

There's a well known little pattern for this and it looks like this:

```
public void SetText(string text) 
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired) 
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(SetText), text);
    }
    else 
    { 
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
```

And there's also the quick dirty fix which I don't recommend using other than to test it.

```
Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Comment: Correct answer, except that the pattern is imho well known :)

Comment: Let's swap those words then, becuase I didn't mean it in the sense of unknown, just the "little pattern" part.

Comment: `Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` - this is exactly what I needed.  I just have a few counters to set from the background thread.  Nothing logically important, just to show on the screen.  I do not care about race conditions... THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

You should check for the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

You should check with InvokeRequired method to see if you are on the same thread or a different thread.

MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx

Your method can be refactored this way

```
private void foo() {
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.foo));
   else
        this.Text = "Test";       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check - [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx)

```
private  void foo()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {   
        this.Invoke(() => this.Text = text);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
```